# Python Regex returning None from non-matching side of OR operator

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which will return TWO matches from either side of an OR like so:

```
def parse_description(description):
    regex = r"^(Created by CreateImage\((.*?)\) for (.*?) |Copied for (DestinationAmi) (.*?) from SourceAmi (.*?))"
    matches = re.finditer(regex, description, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        return match.groups()
    return '', ''
```

with example string:

`Copied for DestinationAmi ami-33dfxxx from SourceAmi ami-9dd6xxx for SourceSnapshot snap-02f5xxx. Task created on 1,518,952,817,897.`

The problem I have is that this returns 4 matches, None, None, ami-33dfxxx, ami-9dd6xxx

Having tried various things at https://pythex.org/ I cannot make this not return 4 matches even though, to my understanding, it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot make it work that way. Either run 2 regexps, or use the PyPi regex module and wrap the alternatives with a branch reset group, `(?|alt1|alt2)`.

Comment: Thanks, this let me to the solution which I'll post below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment suggesting branch reset, this was my eventual solution

```
import regex
def parse_description(description):
    pattern = r'^(?|Created by CreateImage\((.*?)\) for (.*?) |Copied for (DestinationAmi) (.*?) from SourceAmi )'
    matches = regex.match(pattern,description)
    if matches is None:
        return None
    return(matches.groups())
```